# How to prevent normal shuttle double-click event

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I am using an Oracle APEX Shuttle item within a page where the IDs of both my left and right shuttles are: `P10_LIST_LEFT` and `P10_LIST_RIGHT`.

What I am attempting to do via jQuery, is disable the user's ability to perform a double click event on either shuttle, that would "move" an item from the left to right or "remove" an item from right to left.

I have tried the following and unfortunately the double click move from left to right still occurs.

```
$("#P10_LIST_LEFT").dblclick(function(){event.preventDefault();return false;});
```

How can I prevent this normal double-click behaviour?

Comment: `function(){ event.preventDefault(); return false; }`, `event` is unidentified here. Try the following instead`function(event){ event.preventDefault(); return false; }`

Comment: Tried .dblclick(function(event){event.preventDefault();return false;}); and unfortunately it still hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite normal. The doubleclick functionality is initialized in the shuttle-widget itself. All you're doing is binding a new double-click handler which does nothing. After all, what "default event" would you be preventing? It's a normal select list for all intents and purposes.

In `\images\libraries\apex.widget.shuttle.js` you can find the binding of the doubleclick:

```
  $( gShuttleListLeft )
    .dblclick( _move )
    .keydown( function ( e ) {
      if( e.which === 13 ) {
        _move( e, false );
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
```

That's helpful because there just a simple bind and thus can be removed like this:

```
$('#P10_LIST_LEFT', apex.gPageContext$).off("dblclick")
```

Though:
Why would you really want to disable this functionality? It's a pain trying to interfere with this default behaviour and nothing changes for the user except for a reduction in capability. Will the right hand also have double click disabled? Will every shuttle behave like this? If not, that's just confusing.

Comment: to answer your questions - I've actually extended the _MOVE and _REMOVE functionality to also call my own js function. As I only have one shuttle item on the page, I've decided that I only want to call my js function when the user presses the > and < buttons. Double click will be disabled on both sides.